# Keep Getting a Syntax Error when Creating MySQL Trigger

Tags: mysql

I am trying to Create a Trigger that will fire AFTER Insert of a Record where I will see if there is other records similar to this Inserted Record (Same Date) and if so will update a column in the inserted Record.  Once I complete this one I will also update it for AFTER Update as well.  Any Help would be Greatly Appreciated.

```
CREATE
TRIGGER `INSERT_POSTDATEINDEX` AFTER INSERT
ON `zoomloca_listings-dev`.`listings_posts` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DECLARE vNewPostDateIndex INT;
    DECLARE vLastPostDateIndex INT DEFAULT '0';

    SET vNewPostDateIndex = '0';
    SET vLastPostDateIndex = (SELECT POSTDATEINDEX FROM listings_posts WHERE date(POST_DATE) = date(NEW.POST_DATE) ORDER BY POSTDATEINDEX DESC LIMIT 1);

IF vLastPostDateIndex = '0' THEN 
    SET vNewPostDateIndex = '0';
ELSE 
    SET vNewPostDateIndex = vLastPostDateIndex + 1;
END IF;

Update `listings_posts` SET POSTDATEINDEX = vNewPostDateIndex where ID = New.ID;

END
```

Error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: it looks like MsSQL. SET vLastPostDateIndex = SELECT TOP 1 POSTDATEINDEX FROM listings_posts WHERE date(POST_DATE) = date(NEW.POST_DATE) ORDER BY POSTDATEINDEX DESC;

Comment: what is the exact syntax error you are receiving?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER$$
CREATE
TRIGGER `INSERT_POSTDATEINDEX` AFTER INSERT
ON `zoomloca_l' at line 1

Comment: This is for MySQL not MSSQL

Comment: @BradBrewer please add the errors to the question so the question is complete and clear. Then you can use some better formatting as well!

Comment: @nanne I added the error as well as updated the Query to reflect some suggestions that give the new error

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is no `TOP` in `MySQL`. You have to use `LIMIT` instead. Besides, if you are not using `mysql` client, then you should remove `DELIMITER` since it is not a feature of the `MySQL`. Another thing is that to demarcate the end of an `IF` statement in MySQL, you should use `END IF` instead of `ENDIF`.

Comment: That is for MSSQL I am using MySQL

Comment: That's what he said: TOP is for MSSQL, and if you are using MySQL, you should not use it. Use LIMIT.

Comment: I made that change and got the same error but that was one issue I found I am new to MySQL have only done MSSQL in the past.

Comment: you should remove `DELIMITER` thingy since it is only a function of the command line mysql client only and not a regular MySQL language feature.

Comment: @mic4ael I removed the Delimiter Lines and now I get a different Error:  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6

Comment: I updated my code in the original post to reflect the change and the  new error

Comment: replace `ENDIF` with `END IF` and put brackets around the `SELECT` statement

Comment: @mic4ael I made the changes you requested but see get error.  I updated the code snippet above to reflect change

Comment: sorry, my mistake, I meant parenthesis, not brackets

Comment: @mic4ael I changed to () and still get the same error

Comment: according to this http://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/, the code provided is correct in terms of the syntax

Comment: @mic4ael  I am not sure then its weird it stops on  I even made sure the case was the same incase it was case sensitive.                           CREATE TRIGGER `INSERT_POSTDATEINDEX` AFTER INSERT ON  `listings_posts` 
FOR EACH
ROW 
BEGIN 
DECLARE vNewPostDateIndex INT;